# Pass arguments to ruby function in this context

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**disclaimer** I am pretty new to Ruby / Rails

I am using [RPH::Navigation](https://github.com/rpheath/navigation) for creating my navigation menus.  What I am trying to do now is add some sub-nav items and I am doing so like this:

```
  suboptions.each do |group|
    def relpath
      link(group[:link], group[:args]).
    end 
    sub_menu.item group[:name], :path => :relpath
  end
```

`link` is just a method that returns `"#{link}?#{query_string}"` where `query_string` is built from the `args` hash.

What I was originally trying to do was something like

```
    sub_menu.item group[:name], :path => link(group[:link], group[:args])
```

but that put the return value in, and later it is called, returning a method not found error.

My current approach has the problem that `group` is not in scope within `relpath`.  I tried also using `Proc.new` and `lambda`, but since those are not called like normal functions it chokes on them as well.

What can I do to correct this?  What is the proper way?

**EDIT**

If I do

```
suboptions.each do |group|
  def relpath(group)
    link(group[:link], group[:args]).
  end 
  sub_menu.item group[:name], :path => relpath(group)
end
```

Then the error I get is:

```
undefined method `mylink?myarg=1' for #<#<Class:0x007fd8068acd58>:0x007fd8068b07f0>
```

**EDIT 2**

Here is more extensive example of the code.

```
menu.item MyTestsController, :text => 'Test', :if => Proc.new { |view| view.can? :read, MyTest } do |sub_menu|
  suboptions = [{:link => "tests", :name => "All Systems", :args => {:system_id => 0}},
                {:link => "tests", :name => "System A", :args => {:system_id => 1}}]
  suboptions.each do |group|
    def relpath(group)
      link(group[:link], group[:args]).
    end 
    sub_menu.item group[:name], :path => relpath(group)
  end 
end
```

Comment: `:path => :relpath`? Should not it be `:path => relpath`?

Comment: what is the `sub_menu` class? And the API of `item()` Seems you are using the function the wrong way.

Comment: I am not familiar with this library but I would play around trying to set `:path` as a controller action name and maybe adding a `:params => args` to the item function.

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with the navigation library in question, but looking at the documentation at https://github.com/rpheath/navigation it seems you are expected to give the name of a Rails named route helper as the path argument - not an actual URL route. The "undefined method" is simply generated because RPH::Navigation tries to call a helper method by the name that is defined in :path argument, and in this case Rails cannot find a named route helper method called "mylink?myarg=1". So basically, what you would need to do is to create a named route, and use that as the path.